# Qual pattern usa-se para validar regra de negócio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Utilizo repository patterns para pesquisas,salvar e deletar

Gostaria de saber aonde fica melhor a validação de meu negócio...

Por ex:

Preciso verificar se o `item` está em um `contrato` de um `prestador`, e faturar ele com a comissão que está no contrato.

Existe uma regra de negócio aí, aonde se encaixaria melhor fazer isso? Em classes Dao? no próprio repository(não sei se pode ser feito isso)
Aqui aonde trabalho estão passando essa regra no controller, o que eu não acho correto, gostaria de opiniões

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta do @utluiz está correta dentro de um contexto em 3 camadas (apresentação, serviço e dados), mas como estamos falando de MVC, a validação deve ser feita, essencialmente, no `Model`, mas não apenas nele.

### Por que?

A função essencial do `Model` é modelar como a informação circula por dentro do sistema, do ponto de vista de cada entidade. A função essencial do `Controller` é harmonizar e coordenar os fluxos de informação - vindo eles da apresentação, da camada de dados ou de algum serviço externo.

Portanto, **funções de validação de qualquer dado normalmente são geradas a nível de `Model`**. O `Controller` apenas interpreta esse resultado das validações. É feito assim porque a validação é um aspecto ao nível dos dados. Elegantemente, isto é feito no ASP.NET MVC utilizando `Attributes`.

Entretanto, relações entre entidades (`Models`) são resolvidas a nível de `Controller` (comparações, inserções, exclusões, ordenações, etc.).

### Exemplos

Considere o `Model Pessoa` abaixo:

```
public class Pessoa 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PessoaId {get;set;}

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O preenchimento do nome da pessoa é obrigatório.")]
    public String Nome {get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O preenchimento do CPF da pessoa é obrigatório.")]
    [CPF]
    public Decimal Cpf {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos {get;set;}
}
```

Ao salvar uma `Pessoa` em banco, não preciso escrever uma linha sequer de validação no meu `Controller` porque todos os aspectos de dados estão sendo tratados dentro do `Model` de maneira sucinta: o CPF possui um atributo que valida o CPF, o nome não pode ser preenchido vazio e a chave primária precisa ser única (`[Key]`).

O `Controller` nada faz aqui, senão verificar através de outra classe se o `Model` é válido:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Pessoa pessoa)
{
    // Se o Model for válido
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // Gera a chave, salva e retorna
        pessoa.PessoaId = Guid.NewGuid();
        context.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Se não for válido, simplesmente retorna o objeto Pessoa de novo.
    // O resultado das validações está dentro da classe ModelState.

    return View(pessoa);
}
```

Suponha agora que eu quero conceder um desconto num `Produto` adquirido pelo usuário. Este aspecto é tratado em `Controller` porque estamos lidando com uma `Pessoa` e os `Produtos` por ela adquiridos:

```
public class PessoasController : Controller 
{
    ...

    public ActionResult ConcederDescontoUltimoProduto(Guid? id) 
    {
        var pessoa = context.Pessoas.Include(p => p.Produtos).SingleOrDefault(p => p.PessoaId == id);

        if (pessoa.Produtos.Count > 5) 
        {
            var produto = pessoa.Produtos.Last();
            // Vou conceder 10% de desconto no valor do produto
            produto.Preco -= produto.Preco * 0.1;
            context.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

É possível ainda deixar este aspecto negocial a cargo de outras classes específicas, mas considero um esforço prolixo e desnecessário, em que nada contribui para a segurança e responsabilidade de classes do sistema.

Answer (score 5):

O padrão mais usado (mesmo sem conhecimento) é o *Service Layer* (Camada de Serviço).

## Padrão de Projeto *Service Layer*

A arquitetura de uma aplicação geralmente é dividida em camadas que vão do banco de dados até a interface com o usuário ou com sistemas externos.

**No meio disso tudo ficam as regras de negócio.** Elas não fazem parte do modelo de dados, embora o use. Também não seria de responsabilidade dos controladores e muito menos das views, embora estes precisem acessar as regras de negócio.

Isso está bem representado na seguinte imagem:

[image: Service Layer Pattern]

A camada de serviços deve implementar as funcionalidades principais do sistema e prover todas elas para o "mundo externo" através de uma interface bem definida.

Isso evita que o núcleo do sistema seja exposto diretamente às camadas mais "altas" da arquitetura, caso contrário o acoplamento tornaria a manutenção um verdadeiro pesadelo.

## Referências

- [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)
- [Service layers pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_layers_pattern)

Comment: Bacana esse pattern, eu não conhecia, mas poderia dar exemplos de código? Ali na imagem é arquitetura, onde no .net, seria um novo class library

Comment: @Rod Não conheço bem a arquitetura .Net... *Sorry* :(

Comment: Procure sobre BLL C#, é a camada responsável.