# No Ruby on Rails a regra de negócio fica no model?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc, engenharia-de-software

No Java a regra de negócio fica no *controller*, mas ouvi uma palestrante dizendo que no Ruby on Rails a regra de negócio fica no *model*.

Alguém me confirma isso?

Comment: eu ia formular uma resposta, em base acredito que Model nada tenha relação com ORMs, isto ocorreu com o tempo-vs-necessidade. Na verdade o Model são as "regras de negócio", eles acessam dados e atualizam, a unica coisa que ele não deve fazer obter dados diretamente ou enviar dados para a saída (exibir na tela), isto claro visando a organização.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resolvi responder porque não há consenso sobre isso. O que indica que há problemas no padrão MVC. Quando algo é bom de verdade, todo mundo concorda.

- [Tratar regras de negócio no model é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94065/101)

  Aqui as respostas indicam que é no *model*, salvo algum motivo muito forte. Todos usuários que responderam tem boa reputação aqui no site.
- [Como implementar um controller "magro"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100182/101)

  A resposta com vários votos indica que o *controller* não é o local adequado.
- [Regras de Negócio no Banco de Dados - quais as vantagens e desvantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15739/101)

  Aqui se discute se a regra de negócio deve estar no banco de dados ou não. Ora, se tem muita gente que acha que deve estar no banco de dados, então se estiver na aplicação, o mais próximo do banco de dados é o *model* e não o *controller*.
- [O que é Regras de aplicativo e quais são as diferenças em relação às Regras de negócio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117697/101)

  Nessa mostra a diferença entre regra de negócio e de aplicativo. Talvez a confusão seja porque algumas pessoas consideram como regra de negócio o que na verdade é regra de aplicativo. Essa última fica no *controller*. Mas estamos falando de regra de negócio.
- [Em um projeto MVC, onde devo deixar os enums?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/132197/101)

  Mais uma mostrando que tem que saber para que está fazendo cada coisa.
- [Qual camada da aplicação é voltada para processamento de regras de negócio mais amplas e complexas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35189/101)

  Aqui, em uma resposta, a aceita e mais votada, fala para criar uma camada extra. Isso não é bem MVC, certo? De qualquer forma não é para usar no *controller*.

  Tem outra que vai pelo mesmo caminho, apesar de ser um pouco confusa para afirmar isso.
- [Qual pattern usa-se para validar regra de negócio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21145/101)

  Temos uma resposta que diz claramente que deve ficar no *model* e outra que vai para outras camadas que não fazem parte do MVC, mas foi a pessoa que disse na primeira pergunta que era para colocar no *model*, então nem a mesma pessoa concorda com si mesma (ela pode estar dizendo que depende do cenário).
- [Onde deve ficar a regra de negócio no padrão MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114084/101)

  Agora complicou porque a mesma pessoa que respondeu ali na anterior agora está dizendo que é para colocar no *controller*.

  Tem outra resposta bem votada lá que fala que depende. Pelo que entendi vai pelo caminho de que as pessoas confundem regra de negócio com regra de aplicação, mas fala em modelos, então parece tender para o mesmo que vimos antes.

  E tem uma terceira bem votada que mostra que depende do caso. Ela confunde regra de negócio com regra de aplicação. Mas foi respondida pela mesma pessoa que respondeu como diferenciar uma da outra. Se é regra de negócio você pode confiar que a *view* faça isso? Você pode nem ter controle do que é a *view* na aplicação.
- [É errado deixar regra de negócio nos controllers?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32772/101)

  Nessa há um depende de novo. Meu entendimento que lá está escrito que deve colocar no *controller* a não ser que fique grande demais (aãã?!?!).

  A outra resposta vai pelo mesmo caminho indicando que se o sistema for pequeno pode por no *controller*. Acho muito estranho a decisão depender do tamanho do sistema. O que eu até acho é que se o sistema for pequeno não deve usar MVC. Há quem não use MVC até mesmo em sistemas grandes, e se dá muito bem com isso. Mas mudar o padrão de acordo com o tamanho do sistema é esquisito.

> No Java a regra de negócio fica no controller

```
É mesmo? Tem referência sobre isso? O Java todo? Me parece uma afirmação que não se sustenta na forma apresentada. Mas acredito que em algum lugar deve dizer que é assim. Será que a fonte é confiável? Tem outras confiáveis que confirmem isso? Outras que contraditam? São confiáveis mesmo?
```

## Conclusão

Você pode estar pensando que no RoR é diferente. Sim, poderia ser, mas o MVC muda de acordo com a linguagem? Não pode. É isso que estou falando, cada um foi por um caminho.

Pra mim o controlador é só uma camada simples pra fazer o modelo se comunicar com a visão, qualquer operação extra que seja usada estaria errado.

Eu vejo que muitas pessoas acabam tendo dificuldade de pegar do modelo porque o modelo nem sempre está do jeito que precisa, então o controlador tem que contornar isso. E o problema é que o modelo a ser usado deveria ser adequado para essa operação toda e na verdade o modelo que usam é algo básico.

Por outro lado começa ficar complicado. Começa virar DDD em cima de MVC. Então as pessoas preferem violar o padrão para simplificar o código, o que eu acho bom, até que dê problema. Eu acho que o MVC nasceu para um contexto simples e hoje as pessoas precisam ou de algo mais complexo ou algo tão simples que até o MVC não faz sentido. Mas essa parte ainda é opinativa.

É bom deixar claro que eu tenho uma tendência a não gostar do MVC, por isso, a despeito do que muita gente diz, talvez colocar regras de negócio no *controller* não seja tão absurdo. Se ele fosse tão magro assim talvez seja o caso de nem tê-lo, e não adotar MVC. Eu demorei para pensar sobre isso, mas me parece que o MVC exista justamente quando o *controller* é complexo. Sem ele tem só um modelo e uma visão, que uma lógica muito simples já resolve. Claro, depende um pouco da complexidade do roteamento também. Colocar a lógica de acesso direto na visão faz cada ação estar vinculada com uma página de forma direta, o que é só o que a maioria dos sistemas precisam.

Não estou dizendo que regras de negócio devem estar na camada de controle, mas o MVC só deve existir se essa camada realmente tem muita lógica.

Se não tiver tudo isso muito claro, não saber bem o que está fazendo no caso específico, provavelmente tomará um decisão ruim.

Então a resposta simples é que você deve fazer o que mais lhe parece correto. Mas tudo indica que quase todo mundo concorda que a regra de negócio vai no *model* e que em menor grau há alguma concordância que a regra de aplicativo deve ir no *controller* ou *view*, de acordo com a necessidade e complexidade. O que define se é regra de negócio ou de aplicativo é algo um pouco aberto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito boa resposta, 11 anos de Rails e realmente o consenso é regras de negócio no model, com algumas observações para uso de Decorator/Services(ou outro poro como camada extra) para extração de regras de negócio não relacionadas ao BD

Comment: Comecei no PHP estruturado, na faculdade estudei java e agora escolhi trabalhar com Ruby on Rails, por isso estive um pouco confuso. Sou novo no ruby on rails e tenho que melhorar bastante, mas espero ser tão bom quanto você parece ser Luiz Carvalho, obrigado pela força que você tem me dado =D

Obrigado pela resposta Bigown