# Pode LINQ ser considerado regra de negócio?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ddd, regra-de-negócio

Às vezes eu puxo objetos ativos com expressão LINQ.

Utilizar ***filtragem*** com LINQ pode ser considerado regra de negócio e num cenário como DDD (*Domain-Driven Design*)?

Qual o melhor lugar pra se utilizar (em serviços de **Domínio** ou em repositórios na **Infra**).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma genérica assim, não. LINQ não é regra de negócio, ele é um mecanismo de programação. O que você fará com LINQ determinará se o uso específico é regra de negócio ou não.

Em DDD vão dizer que o melhor lugar é nos serviços de domínio. Em outros contextos a maioria dirá que ficará no repositório (no *model*), mas também há quem diga que não é o local adequado. De qualquer forma primeiro precisa ter certeza que aquilo é realmente uma regra de negócio. É comum as pessoas classificarem outras atividades como regra de negócio.

Algumas perguntas sobre o assunto já falam disto, tem uma onde eu [apresento as melhores e faço um questionamento em cada uma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165925/101).

Comment: Obrigado cara, sempre ajudando a comunidade. Continue assim.